# Startup Keystroke Macro

Tags: boot, kiosk

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 using Raspbian with a Chromium browser set to boot and display a web page of a live report, with Chromium refreshing every 2 minutes in order to keep live updated data displayed on the screen. Pretty much a kiosk to display a live report to a workplace.

Unfortunately, every time the Pi boots, I need to log in with the user details in order to see the report (it's IBM Cognos).

I can't get Chromium to auto log-in, so the next thing I can think of is to have a keyboard macro execute at boot, which would be something like

```
*Boot
Wait 10 seconds 
>Enter
Wait 2 seconds
>Tab 
>Enter
```

That would be sufficient to log in. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: sudo apt-get install xautomation

Comment: sleep 10 && xte 'key Return' -x:0

Comment: sleep 2 && xte 'key Tab' -x:0

Comment: May be easier to put the xautomation commanda in a start.sh script

Answer (score 0):

Install xautomation.
Add kiosk.sh to the autostart file and have it launch chromium-browser to a specific page, login and go full screen. Examples of key pushes are included.

```
#leafpad kiosk.sh                                                            
#Adjust the URL

chromium-browser --disable-restore-session-state http://xyz.com -x:0 &
sleep 15 && xte 'key Tab' 'key Tab' 'key Tab' 'key Enter' -x:0

#reset zoom
sleep 10 && xte 'key F11''keydown Control_L''key 0''keyup Control_L' -x:0    


# zoom  in
#sleep 5 && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key equal' 'keyup Control_L' -x:0
# zoom out
#sleep 5 && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key minus' 'key minus' 'key minus' 'key$
# reset zoom
#sleep 5 && xte 'keydown Control_L' 'key 0' 'keyup Control_L' -x:0
```

Comment: Sorry mate, I am very green with unix so I might need a bit more of a fleshed out response.

Do I put that script in ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart??

I will paste the current startup command and please let me know where I should put your commands. 

lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
xscreensaver -no-splash
xset s off
xset -dpms
xset s no blank
usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars <html site>

The session crashed bubble also isn't disabled, so that's not working either. 

@Andy thanks mate

Comment: Add a link in the autostart file the points to the .sh file.

Comment: Make the script first. Make the script executable. Run the script and test it does what you require. Add a link to the script in the autostart file.